# 'Nature Nodding' - author and date?

Tags: quote-source, haldane-macfall, the-wooings-of-jezebel-pettyfer

Haldane MacFall's novel *The Wooings of Jezebel Pettyfer* (1898) has a lead-in quotation that puzzles me. No author is indicated; the quotation is ascribed to a work, 'Nature Nods', but no amount of searching on Google or ABE has brought 'Nature Nods' or its author to light.

The quotation reads in part:

> In her dim-lit lumbered rooms, Nature spins and weaves men's souls; spins she always - never resting - spins the threads of diverse colours in her perfect loom .... Yet ... thus she, nodding at her weaving, knots the ends with faltering fingers - faltering - slips - and mars her craft ....

This is purely a 'for interest' question. I have searched as hard as I can but have drawn a blank. Perhaps MacFall used poetic licence and wrote the supposed quotation himself, but I doubt it.

Comment: *Why* do you doubt that Macphail or MacFall (you used both spellings and I'm too lazy to look it up) didn't invent the quotation? That would seem the most likely explanation for a quotation you can't find anywhere else, but you must have some reason for rejecting it.

Comment: Invented epigraphs are quite common — Walter Scott and George Eliot were fond of them, e.g. [*Ivanhoe* ch.36](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/82/pg82-images.html#chap36) or [*Daniel Deronda*](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/7469/pg7469-images.html).

Comment: MacFall is the spelling in the book. I know less about literature than you do, and accept now that MacFall may well have invented the quotation.  I appreciate both comments.  An invented comment now seems quite likely.